# Saving stream's video in server's database after finishing the live stream

Tags: java, android, database, video-streaming

I'm working on an app that has video streaming functionality. I'm trying to find some documentation on how can I save the stream's video in a server after they finish the live streams so the users can watch the replay later, but can't really find much.

Comment: Do you have any information on whether this is for desktop, mobile or something else and what video playback frameworks you might be using?

Comment: I'd suggest that you save the stream as a file and store its location in your database. Please provide more specific details if you want a more detailed answer.